# Find repeating patterns in sequence data

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I have database of sequential events for multiple animals.
The events are represented by integers so it looks something like:

```
Animal A: [1,6,4,2,5,7,8] 
Animal B: [1,6,5,4,1,6,7]
Animal C: [5,4,2,1,6,4,3]
```

I can manually see that for each event 6 event 1 first happens.
And event 4 happens quickly after a 1,6 combination.
But these are easy to spot in such a small dataset, the real lists are 10000+ events per animal.
Is there a way to use an algorithm or machine learning to search for these kinds of patterns?

Comment: So, you do not know in advance how many patterns a sequence may have and the type of patterns, right?

Comment: @nbro I do not no. I could manually search for patterns but I want to also find some deeper hidden patterns which may not be obvious

Comment: Is the apriori algorithm not fit for this job?

Comment: @random_npc, yeah you are right. I wish I figured that out 2 years ago though :)